# RSpec not showing proper default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a spec for a model named Score with the following code:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: scores
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  score              :integer          default(0), not null
#  exam_id            :integer
#  user_id            :integer
#  questions_answered :integer          default(0), not null
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
#

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Score, type: :model do
  describe "when a new score is initialized" do
    before { @new_score = Score.new }

    it "should have questions_answered value of 0" do 
      expect(@new_score.questions_answered).to eq 0
    end
  end
end
```

The output from this test is as follows:

```
Failures:

1) Score when a new score is initialized should have questions_answered value of 0
 Failure/Error: expect(@new_score.questions_answered).to eq 0

   expected: 0
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

The correct schema information is at the top of that spec, and as you can see, the default is 0 for the `questions_answered` field.

I could see that perhaps this default value would not be set until the object is saved, since the default is set on the database. However, in the console, if I enter `s = Score.new`, here is the output I received:

```
2.2.0 :001 > s = Score.new
=> #<Score id: nil, score: 0, exam_id: nil, user_id: nil, questions_answered: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

As you can clearly see there, Score.new returns an object with the default value properly set to 0. So why is the spec failing?

Comment: Can you verify your test database schema matches the expected schema? It sounds like you may have changed the default after the test database was migrated.

Comment: The schema matched, but after restarting my machine, it works fine. I suspect you're on to the right answer, and maybe RSpec now keeps the test environment loaded between runs? You used to have to use Spork, I think, for it to keep the environment loaded, which I'm not using. Whatever the case, it is working fine now. Thanks!