# rspec returns nil instead of default database value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a spec that posts to an endpoint and then checks to see if the default value has been assigned, but it fails (expected: "uncategorized" got: nil):

```
it 'defaults to uncategorized when none is given' do
  post wikis_path(params: { wiki: { content: 'Some content' }})

  expect(Wiki.last.category).to eq('uncategorized')
end
```

This is the migration:

```
add_column :wikis, :category, :string, default: 'uncategorized'
```

If I create a record in the console, it does assign the default value and if I pass a category value it properly assigns it (this passes):

```
it 'accepts a category if one is passed' do
  post wikis_path(params: { wiki: { content: 'Some content', category: 'a category' }})

  expect(Wiki.last.category).to eq('a category')
end
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong, but this person posted what seems to be the exact same [issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34885039/rspec-not-showing-proper-default-values), only a restart did not solve it for me. What could b causing this behavior?

Comment: Did you run your migration on top of `test` database? In the console you're using `development` database, that might be different...

Comment: I tried running `rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` and then `rspec spec` but I still get the same failure

Comment: you can always check you test database schema with any external editor (ie. Sequel Pro for Mac), and make sure the column really has the default value.

Comment: You were right, it's not getting added to in the test database. I found the problem, the default value wasn't added to the schema for some reason. I rebuilt the schema and the dbs and now all is right with the world. Thank you for the help. If you want to submit the comment as an answer, I will happily accept it